# Replace Fragment results in overlaping fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is a known problem, when I change fragments they overlap.
I followed the examples on the internet with a brand new project to test it out, but no success.
What am I missing here?

1. I started a simple project with the Navigation Drawer Activity
2. I've given the fragment_home and fragment_gallery an as id

   ```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_home"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="333dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
3. I setup  fragment manager with the transaction:

   public void replaceFragment() {
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_home, GalleryFragment.class, null);
   fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }
4. Created a button and set the method as the onClick activity:

   public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
   private View root;
   private FragmentHomeBinding binding;
   private Button button;

   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
   ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
   root = binding.getRoot();
   button = root.findViewById(R.id.button);

   ```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Change Fragment
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).replaceFragment();
        }
    });
    return root;
   ```

   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroyView() {
   super.onDestroyView();
   binding = null;
   }
   }
5. I run the app and press the button, the fragments overlap. What is going on? I've already added a background to the fragments,
   did not work. It has something to do with the BackStack, but how? Why is this so difficult? Why can't I simply add and remove a fragment?

Comment: Can you include your activity's code? The Navigation Drawer Activity template in recent versions of Android Studio uses the [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started), where you don't need to ever write a FragmentTransaction at all.

Comment: Thank this was a useful article you gave me